# how to update a string filed in sphinx?

Tags: sphinx

I want to update the sql_attr_string filed value through php, when i am try to update it following error is shows

searchd error: index femalematrimonyprofileindex47: attribute 'thumbimg' can not be updated (must be boolean, integer, bigint, float, timestamp, or MVA)

Thanks & Regards,
Vishnu

Answer (score 0):

Updating string attributes is not yet implemented.